# Request method 'GET' not supported in Graphdb 8.8.1

Tags: graphdb

I just upgraded from graphdb 8.4.1 to graphdb 8.8.1 - which worked quite well. However I could not access the triple store via sparql and GET anymore and get a lot of 
[WARN ] 2019-03-19 21:08:20,090 [http-nio-7200-exec-8 | o.s.w.s.PageNotFound] Request method 'GET' not supported

How can I switch that on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you upgrade? Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: I downloaded graphdb 8.8.1, extracted it, copied it to a new folder, redirected my graphdb-symlink and copied the data directory of the old graphdb to the new graphdb.

Comment: Can you send us a snippet of the main log here or on graphdb-support@ontotext.com?

Answer (score 0):

The only think I can think of, since I cannot reproduce your issue is that you maybe overwrote some of the files in the directory. I created a repository in 8.4.1 and copied the data folder to 8.8.1 and it works fine. The big difference between 8.4 and 8.8 is the removal of the System repository, but all of your existing repositories will work when migrating.